# mongo client settings throwing exception

Tags: .net, mongodb, .net-core

I am using .Net to connect to a mongo db, when I use client settings as per the code block below I get an exception (below the code block)

```
var clientSettings = new MongoClientSettings()
{
    ConnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
    SocketTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
    WaitQueueTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
    Server = new MongoServerAddress("host", portnumber)
};
var dbClient = new MongoClient(clientSettings);
var _mongoDb = dbClient.GetDatabase(db);
var mongoCollection = _mongoDb.GetCollection<T>(collection);


// exists with code 0 when not able to return with anything
var retVal =  await mongoCollection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
return retVal;
```

Exception :

> One or more errors occurred. (A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode : "Automatic", Type : "Unknown", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/xxxx-mongoapi.documents.azure.com:10255" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/xxxx-mongoapi.documents.azure.com:10255", State: "Disconnected", Type: "Unknown", LastUpdateTimestamp: "2022-09-16T11:18:00.8150834Z" }] }.)

However, if I just add the connection string like this

```
var dbClient = new MongoClient(connectionString);
```

Then this connects no problem.

Can anyone suggest why \ where I have gone wrong please.

Thanks

Simon

Comment: What does the connection string look like? Note that the `MongoServerAddress(string)` constructor is expecting *just a host name*.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have updated the question and the exception

Comment: Except you still haven't provided the one piece of information I actually asked for. If the actual connection string contains sensitive information, you could potentially redact it to some extent, e.g. replacing actual hostnames with "mydatabase.mycompany.com". But we need to be able to see the *structure* of the connection string.

Comment: @JonSkeet the connection string is like this `mongodb://xxxxx-mongoapi:ixRdTyMf2raqcFNR7ZIHatNm878zS3cKOhwYZNdrTxE8c7CPJBbfhXWlG1MArs1jImthSnlnxxxxxxx==@xxxxx-mongoapi.documents.azure.com:10255/?ssl=true&replicaSet=globaldb`

Comment: Ah, I see the failing code and the error has also changed... this is all a bit of a moving target. You're now supposedly constructing a MongoServerAddress specifying a hostname of "host". I suspect you're *actually* passing in "Unspecified/xxxx-mongoapi.documents.azure.com", but we can't actually tell... I'm afraid I don't have time to keep asking for more relevant information at this point.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have given what I understand that you have asked for. Apologies for getting that wrong

Comment: Nope, we still don't know what you're passing in as the hostname or port number. (I assume the port number is 10255.) Maybe someone else can help you with incomplete information - I won't be able to.

Comment: @JonSkeet apologies `Server = new MongoServerAddress("xxxxx-mongoapi.documents.azure.com", 10255)`

Comment: Currently you're not setting `ReplicaSetName` or `UseTls`, both of which you're (effectively) setting in the connection string. Basically I'd suggest making your client settings match your connection string as carefully as possible.

Comment: @JonSkeet I will try this and let you know how I get on

Answer (score 0):

As it mentioned in the comments, you specify different options in connection string and `MongoClientSettings`, to check it, compare `MongoClientSettings` what you fill manually and options you will have with `MongoClientSettings.FromConnectionString()`:

```
var settings = new MongoClientSettings() { .. };
```

and

```
var settings = MongoClientSettings.FromConnectionString(connectionString)
```